# Android Google Maps Marker correct facing rotation

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps

I am showing a live tracking of car on Google Maps including direction in which it is facing.[image]

This is the image I am using to represent a car on a map.
[image]

If you notice the car is not correctly facing straight(facing north) in the above image. Even with proper degrees of rotation it is always slightly towards the right.

[image]

However if I edit and rotate the image 15-20 degrees left it seems to work fine (above).

I have read in tutorials that the image should be facing straight(1st picture) Please help me understand why this rotation seems to incorrect.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to `marker.setRotation` to 0 and then check whether the car icon is facing toward North or not?

Comment: Yes @AmanJain I tried marker.setRotation(0) and markerOpts.flat(true) also. But somehow it still points a bit towards the right.

Comment: So this probably isn't the case with your issue, but my xxhdpi and xxxhdpi icons were slightly rotated, and the other icon densities were correct. It might be worth to just check all your icon densities.

Comment: @Ishaan have you got solution for this .same issue i am facing

Comment: @Ishaan can you help me to get something ? I am fetching current location and putting marker but the current location marker is not stable.

Comment: @SagarHudge I was not able to resolve this. So finally I gave rotation of marker based on previous location and current location results by using location.getBearing().